# Sending an array from backend to angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, http, get

I try to get an array from backend using http.get. In response I have: ["Item1","Item2","Item3"].

```
constructor(private http:Http){
    this.http.get('api').subscribe(
    data => {this.array = data}
    );
}
```

The code above makes this.array = undefined. 
What should I use to get an array?

Comment: where are you accessing `this.array`?

Comment: In constructor, after http.get

Comment: @user852 have you checked my answer?

Comment: You can't just put `console.log(this.array)` after the `http.get` because it is `async`. You have to put it inside the subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Please try to console first whether you are getting `data` or not , also you need to use `.map` (If you are not using `httpClient`) before `subscribe` like this

```
constructor(private http:Http){
    this.http.get('api')
.map(data => {
     console.log(data.json());
     reuturn data.json();
 )
.subscribe(data => {this.array = data});
}
```

Comment: Still array is undefined. When I console.log(data) I get "(3) ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"] "

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing values outside subscribe and because `get` is asynchronous, you are not getting value in it.

```
constructor(private http:Http){
  this.http.get('api').subscribe(
    data => {this.array = data}
    console.log(this.array); <== here it won't be undefined
  );
}
```

If you want to access `array` in component you can use `getter` as:

```
get Array() {
  return this.array;
}
```

in component you can access this by `this.service.Array`

**Solution2**

You can use [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe.